# Reduce the number of item in datagridview while user types in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, c#-2.0, c#-5.0

I have datagrid view filled with values

I have to create a search in datagridview.

```
 private void textBox_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String search = textBox_Search.Text.Trim();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                dataGridView_LicenseKey.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
                webservicelicencesBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("{0}= '{1}'", "nom_centre", search);
            }
        }
```

I use above code.

**Explaination of above code** : When i type first letter in the textbox ;the datagridview  becomes empty unless i type the complete string which matches the value in datagridview.

**What i want :** when i press the letter in the text box , datagridview should reduce .

***For example :***

```
values in Datagrid view 

 1. ABCDE
 2. ABEFG
 3. erdzf
 4. rezfj
 5. Agfe
```

**When I type "A" in text box**

```
value in Data grid view

 1. ABCDE
 2. ABEFG
 3. Agfe
```

**When I type "AB" in text box**

```
value in Data grid view

1. ABCDE
2. ABEFG
```

**When I type "ABC" in text box**

```
value in Data grid view

1. ABCDE
```

and so on.

Need help in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter condition is wrong, it filters exact values only. It should look like this:

```
webservicelicencesBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%'", "nom_centre", search);
```

(Doesn't have to be uppercase)

EDIT:

To show all results again, you have to improve condition when the search term is empty, like this:

```
dataGridView_LicenseKey.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{        
    webservicelicencesBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("{0}= '{1}'", "nom_centre", search);
}
```

I suppose that bad filtering that you mentioned in the comment could happen because the event is fired at EVERY text change. So if you have search term 'AB', deleting one character by time, it would first filter by 'A', and then would cancel another filter because the search string was empty. This scenario would give mentioned result.

Comment: Thanks , it is not working for 1 case. When all the letters from the 
Datagrid is showing all the values related to the last letter deleted.
FOr Example "AB" in the Text box ; Datagridvalue is `1. ABCDE
 2. ABEFG `

now i delete all the character from the textbox. i should get all the 5 values in DGV.
Insted it showing `1. ABCDE
 2. ABEFG
 3. Agfe`

Comment: @GameBuilder: I have edited my answer for this problem.

Comment: you first solution is correct. It just i have put the if condition for string not null.

Thanks alot